# bower install lib in different folders in different computers

Tags: bower, bower-install

I'm trying to install x2js with bower, doing the following:

```
$ bower install x2js
```

In my computer when I do the bower install, I'm getting:

```
$ bower install x2js
bower x2js#~1.1.7           not-cached git://github.com/abdmob/x2js.git#~1.1.7
bower x2js#~1.1.7              resolve git://github.com/abdmob/x2js.git#~1.1.7
bower x2js#*                not-cached git://github.com/abdmob/x2js.git#*
bower x2js#*                   resolve git://github.com/abdmob/x2js.git#*
bower x2js#~1.1.7             download https://github.com/abdmob/x2js/archive/v1.1.7.tar.gz
bower x2js#*                  download https://github.com/abdmob/x2js/archive/v1.1.7.tar.gz
bower x2js#~1.1.7              extract archive.tar.gz
bower x2js#*                   extract archive.tar.gz
bower x2js#~1.1.7             mismatch Version declared in the json (1.1.5) is different than the resolved one (1.1.7)
bower x2js#~1.1.7             resolved git://github.com/abdmob/x2js.git#1.1.7
bower x2js#*                  mismatch Version declared in the json (1.1.5) is different than the resolved one (1.1.7)
bower x2js#*                  resolved git://github.com/abdmob/x2js.git#1.1.7
bower x2js#~1.1.7              install x2js#1.1.7

x2js#1.1.7 public/lib/x2js
```

While in other computer:

```
$ bower install x2js
bower x2js#*                not-cached git://github.com/abdmob/x2js.git#*
bower x2js#*                   resolve git://github.com/abdmob/x2js.git#*
bower x2js#*                  download https://github.com/abdmob/x2js/archive/v1.1.7.tar.gz
bower x2js#*                   extract archive.tar.gz
bower x2js#*                  mismatch Version declared in the json (1.1.5) is different than the resolved one (1.1.7)
bower x2js#*                  resolved git://github.com/abdmob/x2js.git#1.1.7
bower abdmob/x2js#~1.1.7       install abdmob/x2js#1.1.7

abdmob/x2js#1.1.7 public/lib/abdmob/x2js
```

In in my computer creates x2js folder, while in other computer is creating abdmob/x2js folders.

Both computers are using the same version of bower ( 1.6.5 ).

why is happening this ?

Comment: Not sure why, this day when installing the lib, now is creating only the x2js folder, btw the lib was saved as abdmob/x2js in bower.json, I just changed to x2js ( as it was giving error when doing a bower install ).. seems to be working, but is not the solution as the bower --save option saved it that way..

Comment: update: https://github.com/abdmob/x2js/issues/15 seems like the name is the one causing the issues.